# How to compare dates on UI to dates stored in MySQL database in Cypress JS test?

Tags: javascript, date, cypress

In my Cypress test, I am trying to compare a date value retrieved from a MySQL DB to the date appearing on the UI.

Here is my assertion:

```
cy.compareDates(result[0].publishdate, companyDetails.publishedDate())
```

`result[0].publishdate` is the value retrieved from the database - `2022-02-14 16:45:37` (`expectedDate` below).

`companyDetails.publishedDate()` is the UI element that contains the text `14-Feb-2022` (`actualDate` below).

Here is my `compareDates()` function:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('compareDates', (expectedDate, actualDate) => {
  actualDate.then(date => {
    const reformattedDate = new Date(date.text())
    cy.log('reformat: ' + reformattedDate)
    cy.log('ISO string: ' + reformattedDate.toISOString().split('T')[0])
    // expect(reformattedDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]).to.equal(expectedDate.split('T')[0])
  })
})
```

The assertion that I have commented out returns this failure:

[image]

And here are the values being used:

> Reformatted Date: Fri Sep 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

> ISO string: 2015-09-10

What is strange is that the function is working with the below dates:

> Reformatted Date: Wed Feb 28 2007 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

> ISO string: 2007-02-28

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the original question

> In my Cypress test, I am trying to compare a date value retrieved from a MySQL DB to the date appearing on the UI.
>
> The value appearing on the UI is `14-Feb-2022`.
>
> The value in the database is `2022-02-14 16:45:37`

since they are both strings (from comments), you can compare them with less hassle using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/).

Basically, dayjs is really good at parsing date strings into date objects (however the documentation is a bit on the brief side)

For example:

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')

it('tests my dates', () => {
  
  const dateFromUI = dayjs('14-Feb-2022')
  const dateFromDb = dayjs('2022-02-14 16:45:37')

  console.log(dateFromField, dateFromDb)
})
```

You get objects back from `dayjs(myDateString)` that have properties for each of the parts of the date.

So if you want to compare year, month, day and ignore time

```js
expect(dateFromUI.$y).to.eq(dateFromDb.$y)
expect(dateFromUI.$M).to.eq(dateFromDb.$M)
expect(dateFromUI.$D).to.eq(dateFromDb.$D)
```

There are other ways to do the comparison, for example `$d` property has a string representation `Mon Feb 14 2022 16:45:37` and you can do a substring comparison to ignore the time portion.

Or there are diff methods, for example:

```js
dateFromUI.isSame(dateFromDb, 'day')  // returns true
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. When I made this suggested change, the date is giving `Sep` but the actual format has changed to `Sep-11,-2015`.

I'll try to convert both to ISO & see if I can get it working that way

Comment: The DB column for the date is of type `datetime` & the value stored is `2015-09-11 16:15:32`.

And the UI element contains the text `11-Sep-2015`

Comment: Hi @Fody, is it possible to convert a string such as `11-Sep-2015` into the ISO format? What I have seen so far is converting sttrings like `2015-09-11 16:15:32`

Comment: I've tried the first solution above, but I'm getting this error - `expected Invalid Date to equal '2007-02-28T21:00:12.000Z'`

Comment: Hi @Fody, I have updated my question trying to use the ISO reformatting

Comment: The new error message where the compared date is one day out looks to be due to timezone (the `GMT+0000` bit). I'm not sure what's causing that, it looks like one of the values is in a different timezone to `GMT+0000` and is in string format - although you say the DB column type is datetime, does it come into the test as string type? You can check using `console.log(typeof dateRetrievedFromDB)`.

Comment: The date retrieved from the database is a string that equals `2022-02-14T16:45:37.000Z`. When I try to get `typeof` for the UI element, it returns `[object Object]`. What's appearing on the UI is `14-Feb-2022`

Comment: Ok, so the `[object Object]` is just because the jQuery wrapper around the value, but that inner value would also be a string - so we are are dealing with two strings. I just saw the other closed-down question and it looked like it had useful answers, but now deleted. Will see if I can get my head around the issue. One more thing, do you know what timezone the db is set to? Not sure if it's possible to tell, but it might be useful to know the starting timezones.

Comment: I ran `SELECT @@global.time_zone;` (found here https://phoenixnap.com/kb/change-mysql-time-zone). & it just returns `SYSTEM`

Comment: One of the answers in the closed question mentioned something like the `date.text()` isn't in the correct format to use `toISOString()` if that's helpful